# YII:how to get uploading status percentage using CMultiFileUpload?

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

> I created the file upload with CMultiFileUpload. I want to get uploading progress in percentage. How can I do it?  this is my view code..am new to yii..

```
 $this->widget('CMultiFileUpload', array(
                'model'=>$model,
                'name' => 'audiofile', 
                'max'=>1,
                'accept' => $filetype,  
                'duplicate' => 'Duplicate file!', 
                'denied' => 'Invalid file type', 
                'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'opacity: 0;  height: 80px; width: 118px;cursor: pointer;'),
            ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Eajaxupload]

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/eajaxupload/

> EAjaxUpload Works For Me..

Answer (score 0):

There is no single way to do this, in the case of a file upload, there are many extensions that provide a progress bar. If you have a lengthy process to do, you could use ajax to do the work in the background, and make it update a progress bar using JS.

Answer (score 0):

> http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/uploadify/
>   
> You can use uploadify extension if you need progress bar showing the completed percentage

Comment: Is there any option to get status with Cmultiupload